# when iPhone application will raise an exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, exception

I want to know which are the possible places where an iPhone application will raise any exception.

there are many but any has a list that can say that these are possible areas where any exception can be raised by the application.

I tries int i = 1/0 ;but it returned 0 and goes to the next part, as per my knowledge it should raise exception and should go to the catch part.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a language such as Java division by zero would raise an exception. However, in C (and so in Objective-C), the behaviour is undefined. It will not raise an exception. You should manually check for division by zero condition.

From [ISO/IEC 9899 - Programming languages - C](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the ﬁrst operand by the
>   second; the result of the % operator is the remainder. In both operations, if the value of
>   the second operand is zero, the behavior is undeﬁned.

You can read all about exceptions on iPhone in [Exception Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000012-BAJGFBFB)